# Can I make it so a click event only executes if a certain variable is true?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make it so that a user can only trigger an on click event and then execute a function only if a certain variable is true. For example:

```
<button @click='hello'>Trigger</button>

data: function() {
    return {
        isAuth: true
    }
},
methods: {
    hello(){
         console.log('hello')
    }
}
```

I just want to point out that I don't want to only hide the button. I want to make clicks on the button element not trigger unless isAuth: true.

Comment: have you tried `if`?

Comment: I could surround the code inside the hello() function with an if and check but is there a way to prevent the event on even triggering?

Comment: `if (this.isAuth) { console.log('hello') }` ?

Comment: you can't prevent the click from being triggered (easily) but you can prevent the code from being executed

Comment: you could do `<button :disabled="!isAuth" @click='hello'>Trigger</button>`

Comment: You should learn Javascript before jumping into Vue, will save you a lot of time

Comment: You could conditionally assign the event handler. `<button v-on="{ click: isAuth ? hello : {} }">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do the following way, if you really want:

```
<button @click='isAuth ? hello : {}'>Trigger</button>
```

but honestly, this, to me, is not the right way. and I think you should consider calling the function on button click and inside that function, you can use an if statement:

```
<button @click='hello'>Trigger</button>

data: function() {
    return {
        isAuth: true
    }
},
methods: {
    hello(){
      if (!this.isAuth) return;
      console.log('hello')
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button @click='hello'>Trigger</button>
data: function() {
return {
  isAuth: true
 }
},
methods: {
 hello() {
  if (this.isAuth) {
    console.log('hello')
  }
 }
}
```